# Cannot build table in MySQL for related schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
DROP Table if exists Users;
CREATE Table Users(UserID varchar(200) PRIMARY KEY,
Rating INTEGER NOT NULL,
Location varchar(200),
Country varchar(200)
);

DROP Table if exists Item;
CREATE Table Item(ItemID integer PRIMARY KEY,
name1 varchar(200) NOT NULL,
currently INTEGER NOT NULL,
buy_price INTEGER NOT NULL,
first_bid INTEGER NOT NULL,
started varchar(200) NOT NULL,
ends varchar(200) NOT NULL,
UserID varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Description varchar(2000),
FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users
);

DROP Table if exists Categories;
CREATE Table Categories(ItemID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Category varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ItemID, Category),
FOREIGN KEY(ItemID) REFERENCES Item
);

DROP Table if exists Bids;
CREATE Table Bids(ItemID INTEGER NOT NULL, UserID varchar(200) NOT NULL,     Amount varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ItemID, UserID, Amount),
FOREIGN KEY(ItemID) REFERENCES Item,
FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users
);
```

I am a SQL noob, I have only started to learn it. I am having trouble building this database. Every time I run it using mySQL I get an error saying that it cannot build the item, categories or the bids table and I think it is because of my foreign keys and how i have them structured. I have been racking my brain with this for hours and I can't seem to reach the proper conclusion on why I can't build my tables.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this. Thanks!

Comment: Your foreign keys seem to be missing the column name from the *other* table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `references` clauses need the column referred to.  For instance:

```
CREATE Table Item (
    ItemID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name1 varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    currently INTEGER NOT NULL,
    buy_price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    first_bid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    started varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    ends varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    UserID varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(2000),
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
----------------------------------------^
);
```

You need to fix all the foreign key references.

Comment: Holy shit! Duhhh! Thanks a lot. Didnt even see that! One last question sorry! I fixed those errors, but when i run this file on mySQL I am getting a bunch of warnings, do you know what that could possibly be related to?

Comment: @vampyfreak . . . Without knowing the warnings, it is rather hard to say.

Comment: The error I get are:
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'Users' already exists
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'Item' already exists

Comment: @vampyfreak . . . That is strange.  You seem to be deleting the table before attempting to create it.  I would suggest that you delete all the tables and then run the `create`s one at a time.

Comment: That sorta worked, but I had to put the drop statements in a different file and run through that. But now I have two more errors stating:
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'buy_price' at row 1
Warning (Code 1262): Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Comment: @vampyfreak . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  The error you are getting would typically be on an `insert` statement.  This question is not about inserts.